# PHP: Echo IMG src= php echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code working in another document

```
<a href="<?php echo stripcslashes($get_ads_code_one); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $option_upload_url . '/' . $shortname . '_banner1_imagen.'.$get_banner1_imagen_ext; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"  Style="width:100%" /></a>
```

but now i took to next expression:

```
echo "<img src=\"$option_upload_url/$shortname_banner1_imagen$get_banner1_imagen_ext\" >";
```

but seems like the parth isnt correctly implemented, tried diferent things i found on the web but couldnt manage to find a solution...

EDIT:

The image isnt loading when i use the second code.

Comment: What you've posted is fine. We can't help you without knowing what is actually wrong, you're going to have to post a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: We need to see what those variables equate to. Please print their output.

Comment: Also you may use single quotes inside double quotes without `\\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this, php isn't understanding which are your variable names, and you forgot the `.` between `_imagen` and `$get_banner1_imagen_ext`

```
echo "<a href=\"".stripcslashes($get_ads_code_one)."\" title=\"".bloginfo('name')."\">
      <img src=\"$option_upload_url/{$shortname}_banner1_imagen.{$get_banner1_imagen_ext}\" /></a>";
```

I would prefer going with the single `'` at the place of escaping `"`, keep `"` in the html like this:

```
echo '<a href="'.stripcslashes($get_ads_code_one).'" title="'.bloginfo('name').'">
      <img src="'.$option_upload_url.'/'.$shortname.'_banner1_imagen.'.$get_banner1_imagen_ext.'" /></a>';
```

Comment: how would you add the href from the first code i posted, to this code of yours?

Comment: the first option is working perfectly, the second one crashes the whole stuff dont know why. Thanks for the help really appreciated

Comment: @Reversible I forgot the braces `{}` around variables which is not good in the 2nd case as the variables aren't inside `"`

Comment: i was wondering, what if you wanted to make an IF with that code, to make it check if the file exists and then echo the html previously modified by you.

Comment: @Reversible if(is_file("{$option_upload_url}/{$shortname}_banner1_imagen.{$get_banner1_imagen_ext}")){ echo ....; }

Comment: thanks a lot my friend! but it isnt working! have a good one.

Comment: where is that if closed? @CodeBird

Comment: excuse me, i was wondering if you could give some advice about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067570/pagination-in-front-end-module-joomla , if not i totally understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your PHP variables be outside the quotes for them to not be taken as literals.

```
echo "<img src='" . $option_upload_url . "/" . $shortname_banner1_imagen . $get_banner1_imagen_ext . "' >";
```

Comment: What you were trying to do originally looks more like bash.

Comment: Don't forget the single quotes, src='image.png'